# Automate Resharper's "to property with backing field" across many properties and classes?

Tags: resharper

I've got some C# code like this (class file = Status.cs):

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a status entity with the text specified
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someParameter">Some parameter.</param>
    public Status(string someParameter)
    {
        SomeProperty = someParameter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An example of a virtual property.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; private set; }
```

And I want to do 3 things to it:

1. perform a Resharper "to property with backing field" on it
2. get rid of the "private set" and replace it with a regular "set"
3. change the constructor so it initializes the private field instead of the property

So the end result would look like this:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a status entity with the text specified
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someParameter">Some parameter.</param>
    public Status(string someParameter)
    {
        _someProperty = someParameter;
    }

    private string _someProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// An example of a virtual property.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { _someProperty = value; }
    }
```

And my question is:  Is there a way to automate this type of refactoring using, say, the Resharper API ?

Background:

For those who might wonder why I want to do this, it's because:

1. I'm upgrading NHibernate (old=2.1.2.4000, new=3.3.1.4000) and Fluent NHibernate (old=1.1.0.685, new=1.3.0.0).
2. I've got rid of the old NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll and the corresponding line in the config file, so I can now use the default proxy that's built into the latest NHibernate.
3. Between the new implementation of NHibernate and the new version of Fluent, there seem to be two problems when I try to build and run unit tests (part of this is FxCop complaining, but anyway):

a) exceptions are thrown because of the "private set", and 
b) exceptions are thrown because the virtual property is being initialized in the constructor.

So I found that if I make those changes, it compiles and the unit tests pass.

So that's fine for a class or two, but there are over 800 class files and who knows how many properties.

I'm sure there are lots of ways to do this (e.g. using reflection, recursing through the directories and parsing the files etc), but it seems like Resharper is the proper tool for something like this.

Any help appreciated, thank you, -Dave

--In response to the answer saying "just change it to a protected set and you're done":

Unfortunately it’s not that simple.

Here is the error that occurs on running unit tests (before making any changes to any class):

Test method  threw exception: 
NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
.Status: method set_StatusText should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
..Status: method set_Location should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'

So if I change the class as suggested (where the only change is to change the “private set” to a “protected set”), the project will not build, because:

Error   2   CA2214 : Microsoft.Usage : 'Status.Status(string, StatusLocation)' contains a call chain that results in a call to a virtual method defined by the class. Review the following call stack for unintended consequences: 
Status..ctor(String, StatusLocation)
Status.set_Location(StatusLocation):Void    C:\\Status.cs 28

That is why it is also necessary to change any statement in the constructor which initializes one of these virtual properties.

The previous implementation of the NHibernate proxy (ByteCode.Castle) did not seem to care about the “private set”, whereas this one does.

And, admittedly, the second error is because of FxCop, and I could just put an attribute on the class to tell FxCop not to complain about this, but that seems to just be making the problem go away, and initializing virtual properties in constructors is, as I understand it, bad practice anyway.

So my question still stands.  The changes I initially described are the changes I would like to make.  How can I automate these changes?

Comment: Just do replace `private set` with `protected set` and here you done.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and wrote a C# utility to parse such a class file.  The "protected set" idea is valid to a point (thanks Hazzik), but it still needs a backing field.  The below code produces the output I described above (except uses a "protected set").  Regards, -Dave

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
// TODO:  write recursive algorithm to loop through directories
// TODO:  handle generic collections as Fluent NHibernate treats those differently

class Program
{
    public static string ConvertInitialCapitalToUnderscoreAndLowerCase(string input)
    {
        var firstChar = input.Substring(0, 1);
        var restOfStmt = input.Substring(1);
        var newFirst = "_" + firstChar.ToLower();
        var output = newFirst + restOfStmt;
        return output;
    }

    // this gets any tabs or spaces at the beginning of the line of code as a string,
    // so as to preserve the indentation (and/or add deeper levels of indentation)
    public static string GetCodeLineIndentation(string input)
    {
        var charArray = input.ToCharArray();

        var sbPrefix = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var c in charArray)
        {
            // if it's a tab or a space, add it to the "prefix"
            if (c == 9 || c == ' ')
            {
                sbPrefix.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                // get out as soon as we hit the first ascii character (those with a value up to 127)
                break;
            }
        }

        return sbPrefix.ToString();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string path = @"C:\pathToFile\Status.cs";

        Console.WriteLine("Examining file:  " + path);

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist:  " + path);
            throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
        }

        // Read the file.
        var arrayOfLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        // Convert to List<string>
        var inputFileAsListOfStrings = new List<string>(arrayOfLines);

        // See if there are any virtual properties.
        var virtualProps = inputFileAsListOfStrings.Where(s => s.Contains("public virtual")).ToList();

        // See if there are any "private set" strings.
        var privateSets = inputFileAsListOfStrings.Where(s => s.Contains("private set")).ToList();

        if (virtualProps.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found " + virtualProps.Count + " virtual properties in the class...");
        }

        if (privateSets.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found " + privateSets.Count + " private set statements in the class...");
        }

        // Get a list of names of the virtual properties
        // (the 4th "word", i.e. index = 3, in the string, will be the property name, 
        // e.g. "public virtual string SomePropertyName"
        var virtualPropNames = virtualProps.Select(vp => vp.Trim().Split(' ')).Select(words => words[3]).ToList();

        if (virtualPropNames.Count() != virtualProps.Count())
        {
            throw new Exception("Error:  the list of virtual property names does not equal the number of virtual property statements!");
        }

        // Find all instances of the virtual properties being initialized.

        // By examining the overall file for instances of the virtual property name followed by an equal sign,
        // we can identify those lines which are statements initializing the virtual property.
        var initializeStatements = (from vpName in virtualPropNames
                                    from stmt in inputFileAsListOfStrings
                                    let stmtNoSpaces = stmt.Trim().Replace(" ", "")
                                    where stmtNoSpaces.StartsWith(vpName + "=")
                                    select stmt).ToList();

        if (initializeStatements.Count() > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found " + initializeStatements.Count + " initialize statements in the class...");
        }

        // now process the input based on the found strings and write the output
        var outputFileAsListOfStrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (var inputLineBeingProcessed in inputFileAsListOfStrings)
        {
            // is the input line one of the initialize statements identified previously?
            // if so, rewrite the line.

            // e.g.  
            // old line:  StatusText = statusText;  
            // becomes:  _statusText = statusText;

            var isInitStmt = false;
            foreach (var initStmt in initializeStatements)
            {
                if (inputLineBeingProcessed != initStmt) continue;

                // we've found our statement; it is an initialize statement;
                // now rewrite the format of the line as desired
                var prefix = GetCodeLineIndentation(inputLineBeingProcessed);

                var tabAndSpaceArray = new[] {' ', '\t'};

                var inputLineWithoutPrefix = inputLineBeingProcessed.TrimStart(tabAndSpaceArray);

                var outputLine = prefix + ConvertInitialCapitalToUnderscoreAndLowerCase(inputLineWithoutPrefix);

                // write the line (preceded by its prefix) to the output file
                outputFileAsListOfStrings.Add(outputLine);

                Console.WriteLine("Rewrote INPUT: " + initStmt + " to OUTPUT:  " + outputLine);
                isInitStmt = true;

                // we have now processed the input line; no need to loop through the initialize statements any further
                break;
            }

            // if we've already determined the current input line is an initialize statement, no need to proceed further;
            // go on to the next input line
            if (isInitStmt)
                continue;


            // is the input line one of the "public virtual SomeType SomePropertyName" statements identified previously?
            // if so, rewrite the single line as multiple lines of output.

            // the input will look like this:

            /*

            public virtual SomeType SomePropertyName { get; set; }

            */

            // first, we'll need a private variable which corresponds to the original statement in terms of name and type.

            // what we'll do is, write the private field AFTER the public property, so as not to interfere with the XML
            // comments above the "public virtual" statement.

            // the output will be SIX LINES, as follows:

            /*


            public virtual SomeType SomePropertyName
            {
                get { return _somePropertyName; }
                protected set { _someProperty = value; }
            }
            private SomeType _somePropertyName;



            */

            var isPublicVirtualStatement = false;

            foreach (var vp in virtualProps)
            {
                if (inputLineBeingProcessed != vp) continue;

                // the input line being processed is a "public virtual" statement;
                // convert it into the six line output format
                var thisOutputList = new List<string>();

                // first separate any indentation "prefix" that may exist (i.e. tabs and/or spaces),
                // from the actual string of text representing the line of code
                var prefix = GetCodeLineIndentation(inputLineBeingProcessed);

                var tabAndSpaceArray = new[] { ' ', '\t' };

                var inputLineWithoutPrefix = inputLineBeingProcessed.TrimStart(tabAndSpaceArray);

                var originalVpStmt = inputLineWithoutPrefix.Split(' ');

                // first output line (preceded by its original prefix)
                var firstOutputLine =   prefix + 
                                        originalVpStmt[0] + ' ' + 
                                        originalVpStmt[1] + ' ' + 
                                        originalVpStmt[2] + ' ' +
                                        originalVpStmt[3];
                thisOutputList.Add(firstOutputLine);

                // second output line (indented to the same level as the original prefix)
                thisOutputList.Add(prefix + "{");

                // get field name from property name
                var fieldName = ConvertInitialCapitalToUnderscoreAndLowerCase(originalVpStmt[3]);

                // third output line (indented with the prefix, plus one more tab)
                var thirdOutputLine = prefix + "\t" + "get { return " + fieldName + "; }";
                thisOutputList.Add(thirdOutputLine);

                // fourth output line (indented with the prefix, plus one more tab)
                var fourthOutputLine = prefix + "\t" + "protected set { " + fieldName + " = value; }";
                thisOutputList.Add(fourthOutputLine);

                // fifth output line (indented to the same level as the first curly bracket)
                thisOutputList.Add(prefix + "}");

                // sixth output line (the "index 2" value of the original statement will be the string representing the .Net type)
                // (indentation is the same as the "public virtual" statement above)

                var sixthOutputLine =   prefix + 
                                        "private" + ' ' +
                                        originalVpStmt[2] + ' ' +
                                        fieldName + ";";
                thisOutputList.Add(sixthOutputLine);

                // now write the six new lines to the master output list
                outputFileAsListOfStrings.AddRange(thisOutputList);

                isPublicVirtualStatement = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Rewrote INPUT: " + inputLineBeingProcessed + " to OUTPUT:  <multi-line block>");
                break;

            }

            // if we've already determined the current input line is a "public virtual" statement, no need to proceed further;
            // go on to the next input line
            if (isPublicVirtualStatement)
                continue;


            // if we've gotten this far, the input statement is neither an "initialize" statement, nor a "public virtual" statement;
            // So just write the output.  Don't bother logging this as most lines will not be ones we'll process.
            outputFileAsListOfStrings.Add(inputLineBeingProcessed);

        }

        // write the output file
        var newPath = path.Replace(".cs", "-NEW.cs");
        File.WriteAllLines(newPath, outputFileAsListOfStrings);

    }
}
```